# Gingerbread 4.0 build fails for APIDemos

Tags: android

I am new to Android development and was running a build script or the Android-Gingerbread-Release4.0 
As you can see the build is failing. I prefer to figure stuff out myself but would appreciate any hints/helps on where to start looking for this error. I have looked at classPath, verified the junit installation, looked inside the out/target/common/obj/APPS/ApiDemosTests_intermediates/classes-full-debug.jar file etc... nothing obvious is jumping out at me. I suspect it is a configuration issue but am not sure the steps to verify that. Any help is appreciated.

**strong text**
    host Prebuilt: tradefed-prebuilt (out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/tradefed-prebuilt_intermediates/tradefed-prebuilt.jar)
    Install: out/host/linux-x86/framework/cts-tradefed.jar
    Install: out/host/linux-x86/framework/cts-api-coverage.jar
    host Prebuilt: mkfs (out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/mkfs_intermediates/mkfs.ubifs)
    host Prebuilt: run-core-tests-on-ri (out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/run-core-teston-ri_intermediates/run-core-tests-on-ri)
    Copying: out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android.cts.refapp_intermediates/emma_out/lib/classes-jarjar.jar
    target Static Jar: android.cts.refapp (out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android.cts.refapp_intermediates/javalib.jar)
    Copying: out/target/common/obj/APPS/ApiDemos_intermediates/emma_out/lib/classes-jarjar.jar
    target Java: ApiDemosTests (out/target/common/obj/APPS/ApiDemosTests_intermediates/classes)
    development/samples/ApiDemos/tests/src/com/example/android/apis/ApiDemosApplicationTests.java:33: cannot access junit.framework.TestCase
    bad class file: junit/framework/TestCase.class(junit/framework:TestCase.class)
    unable to access file: corrupted zip file
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
    public class ApiDemosApplicationTests extends ApplicationTestCase {
       ^
    make: *** [out/target/common/obj/APPS/ApiDemosTests_intermediates/classes-full-debug.jar] Error 41
    /home/richard/Desktop/freescale/androidimx53/i.mx53AndroidV4/i.MX53-QSB-Android-Gingerbread-Release4.0
    mkimage: Can't open ./ramdisk.img: No such file or directory
    richard-laptop:richard:~/Desktop/freescale/androidimx53/i.mx53AndroidV4/i.MX53-QSB-Android-Gingerbread-Release4.0/scripts

```
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=2.3.3
TARGET_PRODUCT=imx53_loco
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_SIMULATOR=
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
HOST_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
```

## BUILD_ID=GRI40

Answer (score 1):

I recently had a similar problem, although the error messages complained about different classes. Svartalf's answer in [this post](https://groups.google.com/group/pandaboard/browse_thread/thread/2ad9f0ae099e7db1?fwc=1) was helpful to me.